# Is there a solution to use the azure-cognitiveservices-language-luis v0.7.0 package with the otbuilder v4.10 framework?

Tags: azure, botframework

I just downloaded the python botbuilder v4.10 framework, but it doesn't appear compatible with the latest version of the python azure-cognitiveservices-language-luis v0.7.0 package. The framework makes imports that do not exist: *from azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.runtime.models import (CompositeEntityModel, EntityModel, LuisResult)*. Would anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

@Forest73 The recommendation from MS bot framework [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python) to integrate LUIS with your bot framework for python is to use the LUIS app with a helper file to access the entities. With the `botbuilder-ai` package installed in your project update config.py to set the LUIS credentials and the corresponding `recognize()` methods queries the LUIS app to get the corresponding entities.